# Удаление сервиспровайдера привело к поломке сайта!

Tags: php, laravel

После удаления сервиспровайдера страница выдает ошибку http500, причем вообще больше никаких ошибок(не выводится даже стандартная страница ошибок laravel). Пробовал cache:clear, composer dump-autoload, убрал регистрацию сервиспровайдера из config/app.php, все права на файлы установлены нормально. В чем проблема? 
В логах ошибка:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted(tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in project/venvor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 878
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted(tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: смотрите логи в /var/log/

Comment: Var/log на сервере?

Comment: Какой провайдер был удалён ? И каким способом ?

Comment: Я добавил ошибку в вопрос. Посмотрите. Провайдер удален механически через ftp. Провайдер кастомный создан мной

Comment: Самый лёгкий способ - верни удалённый провайдер. Ругается на память, проверь настройку `memory_limit` в php.ini

Comment: Уже пробовал так